# Python: Append-Function adds multiple values

Tags: python, append, multiple-entries

I am coding with python now for a while and since yesterday I stumpled over an issue with the "append" function that seems to appear completely random and I can't find a logic reason for that!

I want to add boolean values to an existing list. My piece of code looks like this:

```
comp_bounds = []
for item_i,item_j in zip(x_bound_min,x_bound_max):
     if item_i == item_j: comp_bounds.append(1)
     else: comp_bounds.append(0)
```

The issue is, the code does not add only one value to the list for each loop but more! However this appears randomly. Sometime it's all fine and other times it adds two or three boolean values. I tried testing it in the console by hard typing the append-function and there the same happend. Here a piece of my console commands:

```
del comp_bounds[:]
None
comp_bounds.append(1)
comp_bounds
[1]
comp_bounds.append(0)
None
comp_bounds.append(0)
None
comp_bounds
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As you can see, I deleted first of all the list values, added a 1 to the list and all was fine. Than I added two times a 0 and there it is! Why did the append command add 6 times a 0?
I tried using "True" and "False" at the beginning, but the same appeared. That's the reason why I switched to "0/1" hoping the issue will be solved.
I am using Visual Studio as IDE. I know the difference between "append" and "extend". My code could easy switch to extend and maybe work fine, but I want to understand the issue to avoid making the same mistake in the futur!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't able to reproduce this issue with the given information, It works fine for me.

Comment: i can not reproduce this behavior with your code in either 2.7 or 3.5 from the command-line python interpreter.

Comment: That's the weirdness of the issue. Asking my collegues and reproducing the mistake only "worked" once, as it usually worked out fine without any mistake

Comment: This code is also working in my installation. I cannot see anything wrong in your code, only in your results :-?

Comment: Just a small improvement in the original code. Instead of a conditional and an append of True/False according to the result of the test, just append the test result: comp_bounds.append(item_i == item_j)

Comment: I see that you work with NumPy. In your case if `x_bound_min` and `x_bound_max` are NumPy arrays, then you can create your `comp_bounds` like this: `comp_bounds = x_bound_min == x_bound_max`